# how import * and __all__ work with submodules imports

Tags: python, import, package

The tutorial (4th paragraph, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) mentions :

> It also includes any submodules of the package that were explicitly
>   loaded by previous import statements. Consider this code:

```
import sound.effects.echo
import sound.effects.surround
from sound.effects import *
```

> In this example, the echo and surround modules are imported in the
>   current namespace because they are defined in the sound.effects
>   package when the from...import statement is executed. (This also works
>   when `__all__` is defined.)

Doubts:

1. In the first statement, which `previous import statements` is it referring to?
2. I cannot understand the statements and the example. To `from sound.effects import *` should not import anything unless defined in `__all__` of `__init__.py` in the package.

Comment: "If `'__all__ '`is not defined, the statement from `sound.effects import *` does not import all submodules from the package sound.effects into the current namespace; it only ensures that the package `sound.effects` has been imported (possibly running any initialization code in`__init__.py`) and then imports whatever names are defined in the package." It says it in your link

Comment: @Natecat can you  please explain the second statement mentioned. What does `because they are defined in the sound.effects package` mean?

Answer (score 1):

1. `previous import statements` refers to:

   ```
   import sound.effects.echo
   import sound.effects.surround
   ```
2. According to CPython 3.6, `from sound.effects import *` only import submodules loaded in `__init__.py` (by defining `__all__`). That means you cannot use symbols in `echo` and `surround` when `__all__` isn't defined.

Otherwise,

> It also includes any submodules of the package that were explicitly loaded by previous import statements.

only works when `__all__` defined in `sound.effects`'s `__init__.py` like `__all__ = ["echo", "surround", "reverse"]`.